# WSO2 Identity Server authentication with SessionID for a user

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have third party thrift services which need to check if user is authenticated using wso2 IS. I am using IS's thriftAuthenticator to authenticate a user and it returns me an authToken.

What I need is the JsessionId for the user and then for each corresponding call pass that JSessionId around and use an aspect to check if that Id has not expired.

My question is how can I find if the JSessionId is still valid for a user and also what is the timeout for that session.

Answer (score 0):

If there are authentication failure exception,  client side code can be implemented to retry again by retrieving new thrift sessionid. So,  you do not need to worry about session timeout in the server side.